# Analysis of Solr index

Tags: solr

I have a Solr 4 instance running which has about about two million entries which are notices published by a stock exchange. To give you an idea of the schema, the main components are as follows:

```
<field name="UID" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" /> 
<field name="company" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="datetime" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="url" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="notice" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="cachefile" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

Is there a way to prepare queries that will give me some interesting facts and figures about the index?

For example:

- Top ten companies that have entries (and the number of notices for each)
- Number of notices published each year
- Most and least popular day/month for publishing notices
- Most popular hour of the day for publishing notices
- Longest notice (by number of characters)

At the moment I'm not sure if this can be done with some clever query syntax, or if I need to employ the use of a module (Statistic/Analytics?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. *Top ten companies that have entries (and the number of notices for each)*: Facet on company, do a *:*-search. If there is a document for each notice, you would get the wanted result in the faceting request.
2. *Number of notices published each year*: Do range faceting on datetime with year as the gap.
3. *Most and least popular day/month for publishing notices*: Add two explicit fields for day and month and facet on those. Maybe also index the weekday, while you are at it?
4. *Most popular hour of the day for publishing notices*: Make a field containing only the hour, facet on that.
5. *Longest notice (by number of characters)*: A function query is the candidate here, but there is no strLength-function. Besides, it would not work as you use a text-field for the notices. Instead you could introduce a new field containing the length of the notice and sort on that.